# writing only the one string of all splitted lines to a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file with around 80000 lines. I am trying to do the following steps :-

1. I am trying to find lines based on its first character. I am able to do that.
2. Now I am left with 7500 lines.
3. I am splitting the lines and displaying its `line.split()[-2]` string.
4. I want to write those strings to a text file, and I am having difficulty with it.

Below is my code, can anybody figure out what am I doing wrong.

```
f4 = open("lines.txt")    #subroutine to find out number of intervals
for i in range(header_lines):
    for line in f4:
     with open("satsid.txt","w") as f5:
       if line.startswith(" 12"):
          print line.split()[-2]
          f5.write('line.split()[-2]')
          numints = numints+1;
       if not line:
           break
```

Comment: What is the loop `for i in range(header_lines):` supposed to achieve? You cannot read from `f4` repeatedly without re-opening or rewinding to the start, but I never use `i` in the loop so I suspect it is entirely redundant here.

Comment: 1)I am opening the file completely, reading it after header_line(say is 15, i am reading the file from 16th line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the loop over `header_lines` the following would replicate your code without re-opening the `f5` file each time (which clears it each time you reopen):

```
with open("lines.txt") as f4, open("satsid.txt","w") as f5:
    for line in f4:
        if line.startswith(" 12"):
            f5.write(line.split()[-2] + '\n')
```

This writes the 1-but-last element from the line to `f5` if the line starts with `' 12'` (a space, then a 1, then a 2). I add a newline between these values in the output file.

If you need to skip a number of lines (say a number stored in `header_lines`) in `f4`, use [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to limit the loop:

```
from itertools import islice

with open("lines.txt") as f4, open("satsid.txt","w") as f5:
    for line in islice(f4, header_lines, None):
        if line.startswith(" 12"):
            f5.write(line.split()[-2] + '\n')
```

`islice()` will skip over `header_lines` lines, then pass through the rest of the file until the end.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your answer.